# What did Hindu's call themselves before 'Hindu'?

Tags: name

What did Hindu's call themselves before they were referred to as 'Hindu' from other cultures?

I read that it was foreigners that referred to people from India or near the Indus river as 'Hindi' or Hindu.

Comment: They called themselves nothing. Because Hindu is not group of just one type of people following only one religion, one god, one philosophies.... There were (and still are) Vaishnavas, Shaivas, Shaktas, Sauryas, Gaanapatyas, Skaandas, Agneya, et cetera groups. But they did not say we are separate groups but collectively we are Called some name.

Comment: 1. sanatana dharma anuja/anujAta. 2. They were also called adherents to vaidika dharma 3.